# Vue3 - Suspense waiting for async variable

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, office-js, office-addins

I have below two components (parent and child)

```
.
├── Index.vue (Parent)
└── _GetShipment.vue (Child)
```

In the `Index.vue` I am trying to get the content of the e-mail body using Office.js's getAsync:

```js
<script>
import Shipment from './_GetShipment.vue';
import { ref, defineComponent, Suspense } from 'vue';


export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const shipments = ref([]);

        shipments.value = Office.context.mailbox.item.getRegExMatchesByName('ShipmentNumbers');

        if (!shipments.value) {
            Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
                "text",
                function (result) {
                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        let matches = result.value.match(/S\w{3}\d{8,9}/ig);
                        if(matches){
                            shipments.value = matches;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        return {
            shipments,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Shipment
    },
})
</script>

<template>
    <Suspense>
        <Shipment :id="shipments[0]" />
        <template #fallback>
            Loading...
        </template>
    </Suspense>
</template>
```

In the child component, I fetch data using the `async setup` method:

```js
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
    props: ['id'],
    async setup(props) {
        const shipment = ref();
        await fetch(route('getShipment', {id : props.id}))
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => shipment.value = data);
        return { shipment };

    }
};
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(shipment, null, 2) }}</pre>
    </div>
</template>
```

When navigating to my page, `Index.vue`, the `Loading...` fallback message from `Suspense` is being shown, and the async data from the child is also being loaded.**however**, the console also throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I guess this is because when `Index` is loaded, the `shipments` variable is not set, but will be set just after load.

If I render the child component using a `v-if`, like so:

```js
<template>
    <Suspense>
        <Shipment v-if="shipments" :id="shipments[0]" />
        <template #fallback>
            Loading...
        </template>
    </Suspense>
</template>
```

Then the fallback loading message is not being shown. How can I call an async function (`getAsync()`) whilst still showing the loading message using `Suspense`?

Comment: not sure if `:id="shipments?.[0]"` would help

Comment: @JaromandaX That will throw a new error, noticing me that `id` is required for the `fetch` action in the child component :/

Comment: then you'd fix that code to not blindly make a request with no id :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Jaromanda X put me on the right track:

> not sure if `:id="shipments?.[0]"` would help

When the component is loaded, the `shipments` variable is empty - as it is waiting for the async function `getAsync` to finish.

Adding the code from Jaromanda X to the parent component:

```js
<Shipment :id="shipments?.[0]" />
```

And then in the child component, I added this under the `async setup(props)` method:

```js
while(!props.id){
   await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
}
```

This got rid of the error in the log, the loading message is successfully showing until the `fetch` is done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to promisify the `getAsync()`, so you can await it, as with `callback` syntax the suspense can't wait for it.

```
<script>
import Shipment from './_GetShipment.vue';
import { ref, defineComponent, Suspense } from 'vue';


export default defineComponent({
    async setup() {
        const shipments = ref([]);

        const getAsyncMailbox = async () => {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
                "text",
                function (result) {
                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        let matches = result.value.match(/S\w{3}\d{8,9}/ig);
                        if(matches){
                            shipments.value = matches;
                        }
                    }
                    resolve()
                }
            );

           })

        }

        shipments.value = Office.context.mailbox.item.getRegExMatchesByName('ShipmentNumbers');

        if (!shipments.value) {
            await getAsyncMailbox()
        }

        return {
            shipments,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Shipment
    },
})
</script>

<template>
    <Suspense>
        <Shipment :id="shipments[0]" />
        <template #fallback>
            Loading...
        </template>
    </Suspense>
</template>
```

Comment: This gives me the error `Component <Anonymous>: setup function returned a promise, but no <Suspense> boundary was found in the parent component tree. A component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order to be rendered.`

Comment: You need to set `Index` component inside a <Suspense>